# How to search for only a specific string within a variable in R

Tags: r, grepl

In my code I have a string variable (`panel_name`) which can have a number of different forms along the lines of: `CVD II` or `Onc, IR` or `CVD II, CVD III` and so-on. I also have a function which then searches this variable for specific strings, and based on their presence outputs other strings.

So, for example, I have:

```
if (grepl("CVD II", panel_name) == TRUE){

    panel_pref = ""
    panel = "CVD2"

  } else if (grepl("CVD III", panel_name) == TRUE){

    panel_pref = ""
    panel = "CVD3"

  }
```

The issue I am coming across however is in an example input of `CVD II`, this will return as "TRUE" if `panel_name == CVD III` and this is not what I want.

My current solution is to just invert the above code, so it becomes:

```
if (grepl("CVD III", panel_name) == TRUE){

    panel_pref = ""
    panel = "CVD3"

  } else if (grepl("CVD II", panel_name) == TRUE){

    panel_pref = ""
    panel = "CVD2"

  }
```

But this feels a little messy, so I am wondering if there is a way to search for a string specifically within another string.

I can't use if x == y (for example) because the variable sometimes contains more than one of the "names" I am searching for, but `grepl` seems not to have allow exclusions.

Comment: Thanks for posting what you have tried. Hard to say without example data, but you could check out `%in%`. Or you could use something like `$` in [regex](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) to indicate the end of a string. One more note: I do not know how many conditions you are changing, but `dplyr::case_when` may be worth looking into. If you run into more issues post your example data and expected results. Good luck!

Comment: If you use perl syntax (in `grepl`, set `perl = T`), the regex `CVD II(?!I)` will get `CVD II` not followed by another `I`. As an alternative route, it might work in your situation to forgo the `if else` logic and just extract the number of `I`s that occur after `CVD\\s`, since you're then pasting that number to `CVD`.

Comment: @Andrew The ```dplyr::case_when``` might in fact be more along the lines of what I was looking for in fact. Because, as you say, I have more cases than just looking for the difference between ```CVD II``` and ```CVD III``` but I haven't ever used that command so I might stick with what I have (and is working) for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabor117,

You should check out ?regexp and expand your use of the regular expressions available to you there.  For example, if it's just about distinguishing "CVD II", from "CVD III", then you can just indicate the end of the string with $ as below:

```
a <- "CVD III"
grepl(x=a,pattern="CVD II$")
```

Depending on your situation, there could be much better solutions.

Also, if you are new to regular expressions, it helps to be able to experiment with the wildcards and other regex syntax.  I would point you too one of the regex resources out there.  My personal favorite is https://regex101.com/

Comment: I guess, I should point out that regex does allow exclusions, but they probably aren't as flexible as you would like.  Using the ^ character in square brackets will allow for this.  Such as, pattern="CVD II[^I]".  Just note, that if you put more than one character in the square brackets, it's treated like an unordered set of characters.  So, pattern="CVD II[^not this phrase]" wouldn't work like one might think.

Comment: This seems like it would solve the problem quite neatly! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A couple regex options to use in your `if` / `else` tests:

```r
test_cases <- c("CVD II", "CVD III")
```

Is `II` found at the end of the string?

```r
grepl("CVD II$", test_cases)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Is `II` found at the boundary of a word?

```r
grepl("CVD II\\b", test_cases)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Is `II` found without being followed by another `I`? Requires perl syntax.

```r
grepl("CVD II(?!I)", test_cases, perl = T)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Or you can skip the `if else` tests and use a vectorized search and paste. The `stringi` and `stringr` packages have several convenience functions.

If you don't expect `I` to show up otherwise, you can simply count occurrences of `I` and paste that to `CVD`.

```r
paste0("CVD", stringi::stri_count_regex(test_cases, "I"))
#> [1] "CVD2" "CVD3"
```

Or, a somewhat strange option: Your strings contain roman numerals. Extract the `I` strings that occur after `CVD`:

```r
stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(test_cases, "(?<=CVD )(I+)")
#> [1] "II"  "III"
```

You could expand that for higher roman numerals by including something like `([IVX]+)`. Then convert them to roman numeral objects with `utils::as.roman`, then regular numeric objects, then paste.

```r
paste0("CVD", 
       as.numeric(as.roman(stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(test_cases, "(?<=CVD )(I+)"))))
#> [1] "CVD2" "CVD3"
```

Comment: A lot of useful stuff here... I hadn't considered making a list of all the different cases I was testing for.

Comment: How much detail you go into really depends on how well you need it to scale. If you only need to differentiate between `CVD II` and `CVD III`, the first 3 examples handle that. But they don't scale to more possible values or more complex strings